# Matlab ode45 new variable

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a Matlab code that simulates frisbee flight dynamics. I would like to add a wind variable. I did it, but after seeing the plots I think my wind is reducing the speed of the disc. I mean it should change the speed of the disc but via lift and drag force, now it looks like wind speed variable direcly changes disc speed variable. What I want is to affect only the lift and drag forces with wind, but I can't make it work. Here is my current code that is not working. This is an external M-file which is used by the `ode45` function in the main script:

```
[t,x]=ode45(@discfltEOM,tspan,x0,options,CoefUsed);
```

```
function xdot=discfltEOM(t,x,CoefUsed)
% Equations of Motion for the frisbee
% The inertial frame, xyz = forward, right and down
global m g Ia Id A d rho
global CLo CLa CDo CDa CMo CMa CRr
global CL_data CD_data CM_data CRr_rad CRr_AdvR CRr_data
global CMq CRp CNr
% x = [ x y z vx vy vz f th fd thd gd gamma Wx Wy]
% 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
%% give states normal names
vx = x(4);
vy = x(5);
vz = x(6);
f = x(7);
th = x(8);
st = sin(th);
ct = cos(th);
sf = sin(f);
cf = cos(f);
fd = x(9);
thd= x(10);
gd = x(11);
Wx = x(13);
Wy = x(14);
%% Define transformation matrix
%% [c]=[T_c_N] * [N]
T_c_N=[ct st*sf -st*cf; 0 cf sf; st -ct*sf ct*cf];
%% [d]=[T_d_N] * [N]
%T_d_N(1,:)=[cg*ct sg*cf+sf*st*cg sf*sg-st*cf*cg];
%T_d_N(2,:)=[ -sg*ct cf*cg-sf*sg*st sf*cg+sg*st*cf];
%T_d_N(3,:)=[ st -sf*ct cf*ct]
[evec,eval]=eig(T_c_N);
eigM1=diag(eval);
m1=norm(eigM1(1));
m2=norm(eigM1(2));
m3=norm(eigM1(3));
c1=T_c_N(1,:); % c1 expressed in N frame
c2=T_c_N(2,:); % c2 expressed in N frame
c3=T_c_N(3,:); % c3 expressed in N frame
%% calculate aerodynamic forces and moments
%% every vector is expressed in the N frame
vel = [vx vy vz]; %expressed in N
vmag = norm(vel);
Vwiatr = [Wx Wy 0];
Vw = norm(Vwiatr);
vc3=dot(vel,c3); % velocity (scalar) in the c3 direction
vp= [vel-vc3*c3]; % subtract the c3 velocity component to get the velocity vector
% projected onto the plane of the disc, expressed in N
alpha = atan(vc3/norm(vp));
Adp = A*rho*(vmag-Vw)*(vmag-Vw)/2;
uvel = vel/vmag; % unit vector in vel direction, expressed in N
uvp = vp/norm(vp); % unit vector in the projected velocity direction, expressed in N
ulat = cross(c3,uvp); % unit vec perp to v and d3 that points to right, right?
%% first calc moments in uvp (roll), ulat(pitch) directions, then express in n1,n2,n3
omegaD_N_inC = [fd*ct thd fd*st+gd]; % expressed in c1,c2,c3
omegaD_N_inN = T_c_N'*omegaD_N_inC'; % expressed in n1,n2,n3
omegavp = dot(omegaD_N_inN,uvp);
omegalat = dot(omegaD_N_inN,ulat);
omegaspin = dot(omegaD_N_inN,c3); % omegaspin = p1=fd*st+gd
AdvR= d*omegaspin/2/vmag ; % advanced ration
if CoefUsed==1 % using short flights coefficients
CL = CLo + CLa*alpha;
alphaeq = -CLo/CLa; % this is angle of attack at zero lift
CD = CDo + CDa*(alpha-alphaeq)*(alpha-alphaeq);
CM=CMo + CMa*alpha;
%CRr= CRr*d*omegaspinv/2./vmagv';
%CRr= CRr*sqrt(d/g)*omegaspinv; % this line produces NaN, so leave it in Mvp equation
%Mvp = Adp*d* (CRr*d*omegaspin/2/vmag + CRp*omegavp)*uvp; % expressed in N
Mvp = Adp*d*(sqrt(d/g)*CRr*omegaspin + CRp*omegavp)*uvp; % expressed in N
end % if CoefUsed==1 % using short flights coefficients
if CoefUsed==2 % using potts coefficients
%% interpolation of Potts and Crowther (2002) data
CL = interp1(CL_data(:,1), CL_data(:,2), alpha,'spline');
CD = interp1(CD_data(:,1), CD_data(:,2), alpha,'spline');
CM = interp1(CM_data(:,1), CM_data(:,2), alpha,'spline');
CRr = interp2(CRr_rad,CRr_AdvR,CRr_data,alpha,AdvR,'spline');
Mvp = Adp*d* (CRr* + CRp*omegavp)*uvp; % Roll moment, expressed in N
end % if CoefUsed==2 % using potts coefficients
lift = CL*Adp;
drag = CD*Adp;
ulift = -cross(uvel,ulat); % ulift always has - d3 component
udrag = -uvel;
Faero = lift*ulift + drag*udrag; % aero force in N
FgN = [ 0 0 m*g]'; % gravity force in N
F = Faero' + FgN;
Mlat = Adp*d*(CM + CMq*omegalat)*ulat; % Pitch moment expressed in N
Mspin = [0 0 +CNr*(omegaspin)]; % Spin Down moment expressed in C
M = T_c_N*Mvp' + T_c_N*Mlat' + Mspin'; % Total moment expressed in C
% set moments equal to zero if wanted...
% M=[0 0 0];
% calculate the derivatives of the states
xdot = vel';
xdot(4) = (F(1)/m); %accx
xdot(5) = (F(2)/m); %accy
xdot(6) = (F(3)/m); %accz
xdot(7) = fd;
xdot(8) = thd;
xdot(9) = (M(1) + Id*thd*fd*st - Ia*thd*(fd*st+gd) + Id*thd*fd*st)/Id/ct;
xdot(10) = (M(2) + Ia*fd*ct*(fd*st +gd) - Id*fd*fd*ct*st)/Id;
fdd=xdot(9);
xdot(11) = (M(3) - Ia*(fdd*st + thd*fd*ct))/Ia;
xdot(12) = x(11);
xdot(13) = Wx;
xdot(14) = Wy;
xdott=xdot';
% calculate angular momentum
H = [Id 0 0 ; 0 Id 0; 0 0 Ia]*omegaD_N_inC';
format long;
magH = norm(H);
format short;
state=x';
```

`Wx` and `Wy` are wind vectors. I'm trying to affect the `Adp` variable because it is direcly connected with lift and drag. I made `Wx = 1` [m/s] and the effect is immense, but should be very little. I'm terrible with Matlab so I'm sure I making some kind of stupid mistake from not understanding well how it all works.

Comment: @horchler, we might not agree on certain grammatical aspects, but MathWorks has used MATLAB as their official product name, hence my edit to capitals.

Comment: @Adriaan: I was in the middle of my edits when yours went through. Since I had fixed a lot more grammar, I still submitted mine. I could care less if the branded all caps Matlab is used or not.

Comment: I see no help ;< Maybe someone can tell me how can I display values of Vwiatr, Vw and Adp?